# Concurrent access to HSQLDB embedded instance

Tags: hsqldb

What are the options - if any - for allowing read-only access from another process to an embedded HSQLDB instance? Within an application server there is `org.hsqldb.server.Servlet` but otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a server from the application (process) that connects to the database in embedded mode. Other processes can then connect to this server. See below:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#listeners_appstart-sect